# playing sound file onMouseOver event

Tags: javascript, html, xhtml

i want my sound file to play when some over mouse on my image.my code is not working any one can help,if some 1 did this plz let me know the code.thanx in advance

```
function Sound(surl) {
  document.getElementById("myspan").innerHTML=
    "<embed src='"+surl+"' hidden=true autostart=true loop=false>";
}


<span id=myspan></span>
<form>
<img src="imag.jpg" onMouseOver="Sound('success.wav')" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Working fine code tested by me You
>   did a mistake in escape characters in
>   embed

```
<html>
<head>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

function Sound(surl) {
alert("working");<!-- this will ensure function is called successfully-->

document.getElementById("myspan").innerHTML=
"<embed src=\""+surl+"\" hidden=\"true\" autostart=\"true\" loop=\"false\" />";
}
</script>

</head>
<body>
<span id="myspan"></span>
<form>
<img src="imag.jpg" onMouseOver="Sound('success.wav')" />   
</form>
</span>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: when i run my page than it let me  to install plugin and than its showing no plugin were found can u plz tell me wts the suitable plugin easy ti intigrate

Comment: if you are using firefox it will automatically popup you to install missing plugin install it and then open page your audio will run perfectly!

Comment: http://www.htmlcodetutorial.com/embeddedobjects/_EMBED.html
on above page also you required plugin .. install it automatically

Answer (score 4):

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function sound(surl) {
        document.getElementById("myspan").innerHTML =
        "<embed src="+surl+" hidden=true autostart=true loop=false>";
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>

<span id="myspan"></span>

<form>
    <img src="image.jpg" onmouseover="sound('success.wav')" />
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

This has been tested and is working. May just want to change the cursor when you mouse over in CSS.

Comment: Whoa, people still use `embed` tags?

Comment: Haha, it's a good answer. One day `audio` will be universally supported. One day...

Comment: From the future: Yeah, pretty much now.