# Using Javascript to change an onhover sound based on user selection

Tags: javascript, html, css, html5-audio, onhover

I'm terribly new to HTML and Javascipt. I'm working on a project that will allow the user to select a ukulele chord from a dropdown menu, and then mouse over an image to play the sound of the chord. I have placed all of the sound clips in an array, and already have the code working to where the image will change based on user selection. I just can't seem to get the audio to play, despite the fact that I'm trying to use the same method for both the image and audio. Here is the script I have so far:

```
<script>

        $(document).ready(function(){

            var pictureList = [
                "images/ukeneccsmall.png",
                "images/c_chord.png",
                "images/d_chord.png",
                "images/f_chord.png",
                "images/g_chord.png",
                "images/aminor_chord.png" 
            ]; 

            var soundList = [
                "sounds/No_chord.m4a",
                "sounds/C_chord.m4a",
                "sounds/D_chord.m4a",
                "sounds/F_chord.m4a",
                "sounds/G_chord.m4a",
                "sounds/Am_chord.m4a"
            ];

            $('.button').on('click',function() {


            });

            $("#pickme").change(function() {
                //console.log("Drop down changed!");
                var picked = $("#pickme option:selected").val();
                var imgsrc = pictureList[picked];
                var songsrc = soundList[picked];

                $('#neckimg').attr("src",imgsrc);
                playSound(songsrc);
            });

        $('#picDD').change(function () {
            var val = parseInt($('#picDD').val());
            //selects all images
            //make individual ID
            $('img').attr("src",pictureList[val]);
        });                

        var div = $(".dropdown-content");
        var div = document.getElementsByClassName('dropdown-content');
        for(var  i =0;i<div.length;i++) {
            for(var  j =0;j<div[i].children.length;j++) {
                div[i].children[j].addEventListener('click',function(){
                    this.parentNode.previousElementSibling.innerHTML = this.innerHTML;
                });
            }
        }

        function playSound(songsrc) {
            var soundPlay = songsrc;
            soundplay.currentTime = 0
            soundPlay.play();
        }     

        });


    </script>
```

Here is the HTML that I currently have for the image that will be moused over:

```
<img src="images/ukeneccsmall.png" height="567px" width="250px" left="10px" margin="10px" id="neckimg" float="left" align="middle" onmouseover="playSound()" >
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Your `playSound` function has some issues:

```
function playSound(songsrc) {
    var soundPlay = songsrc; //this var is camelCase
    soundplay.currentTime = 0 //soundplay should be undefined and if you're not on es6 (I guess), you'll need a semikolon as well
    soundPlay.play();
}
```

change that function to:

```
function playSound(songsrc) {
    var soundPlay = songsrc;
    soundPlay.currentTime = 0;
    soundPlay.play();
}
```

Or make it simpler, because you don't really have to declare a new variable in such a small helper function:

```
function playSound(songsrc) {
    songsrc.currentTime = 0; //I personally always prefer semikolons, doesn't matter what kind a es-version it is
    songsrc.play();
}
```

Your attibute `onmouseover="playSound()` has no parameter, but your function `playSound(songsrc)` expects one.
Take a look at this question [playing-sound-file-onmouseover-event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5748174/playing-sound-file-onmouseover-event)